# the write button writes the text but the read button is not working

Tags: c#

```
 private void btnRead_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {try{
            FileStream f = new FileStream("demo.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f);
            tb1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            f.Close();
           }Catch(Exception ee){
             MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
             }
        }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/common-i-o-tasks

Comment: Try using the full path of that file, you app may look in a different folder than you think

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in linqpad, everything works fine. However, there's a typo, the 'Catch' should be 'catch' though.

You can set a break point on the reader, and see if it read anything.